# Dynamically create content of table php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a table where users choose which week they want - 1 to 52, and then across the top of the table have the days Monday through Sunday and down the side 5 different meal times.

I would like to know how i would fill the contents of the table with values stored in a database that correspond the the right day and meal time? In a .php webpage. for example:

```
             Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    ....
Breakfast    Meal 1    Meal 3     Meal 6
             Meal 2

Lunch        Meal 3
             Meal 4
```

Each meal has an id linking it to a meal time and a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you know the data access information for your table you could use this script: [PHP MySQL tutorial - Retrieve data](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php_2.htm)

You will need to format the table accordingly.  I would recommend using google to figure out how to create the table.